# Protect php page with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER AccessKey

Tags: php, json, header

I would like to protect a JSON with an AccesKey send in the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER. How can I check if the correct key is passed in the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('AccessKey: 12345'));

Something like:

```
IF (AccessKey == "12345") {
var_dump($json); 
}else{
FORBIDDEN;
}
```

Comment: The headers will be part of `$_SERVER`. You have the basic logic down already.

Comment: Thank you! Solved. if($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESSKEY']== "12345") { did the trick